# How to write comment behind text in one line if this sentence is divided into many lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a simple example, actually statement is too long to write in one line, and I have to write some necessary comment in each line, but when I add `\` and `#`, it shows error here, how to solve this problem?

```
   a, b, c = 1,2,3 
    if a > 10 \ #add element a
    or b > 10 \ #add element b
    or c > 10: #add element b
        print("good")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put this in bracket.

```py
a, b, c = 1,2,3
if (a > 10 #add element a
or b > 10  #add element b
or c > 10): #add element c
    print("good")
```